# How can i serve an Ubuntu installation Image on my Server for networkboot?

Tags: installation, boot

I Would like to Install Ubuntu on my Netbook, that has no CD-Rom.

can I serve the Live-CD on my other computer, so I can install it via the Bios Network-Boot on my Netbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this help: [How do I boot Ubuntu from the network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272425/how-do-i-boot-ubuntu-from-the-network/272454?noredirect=1#272454)
and this [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer), that is linked there. [This tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro) also helped

I collected it all together:

### Installation and configuration of a PXE-Server

This is what you have to do on Ubuntu 12.10:

```
apt-get install inetutils-inetd tftpd-hpa dnsmasq
```

edit `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` so it looks like this:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="-l -s -v -v"
```

Mount the Lubuntu 12.10 Desktop ISO and copy it to the tftpboot folder:

```
mkdir /mnt/loop
mount -o loop -t iso9660 /media/Daten/installer/Linux/lubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso /mnt/loop
mkdir /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-installer
cp -R /mnt/loop/* /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-installer
umount /mnt/loop
```

edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and set there:

```
interface=eth0

dhcp-range=10.0.0.220,10.0.0.250,12h

dhcp-boot=/pxelinux.0,0.0.0.0
```

now get the `pxelinux.0` file by installing SYSLINUX:

```
apt-get -y install syslinux
```

Copy the PXELINUX bootstrap to the root of our TFTP server.

```
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/pxelinux.0 /var/lib/tftpboot
```

create the file `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` [(source)](https://wiki.xkyle.com/Building_A_PXE_Server#Ubuntu):

```
mkdir /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/

echo "
LABEL u
KERNEL ubuntu-installer/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND tasks=standard pkgsel/language-pack-patterns= pkgsel/install-language-support=false vga=normal initrd=ubuntu-installer/casper/initrd.lz -- quiet 
PROMPT 1
DISPLAY banner.txt
" >> /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
# (adjust KERNEL and initrd to the correct path on your machine!)
```

Then create the banner.txt file:

```
echo "press 'u' to boot ubuntu" >>/var/lib/tftpboot/banner.txt
```

configure your eth0 card:

```
service network-manager stop 

ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

restart the services:

```
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
killall in.tftpd
service tftpd-hpa restart
```

now everything should work fine, just connect another computer to your machine on eth0 and select the boot option 'u' there

---

### Errorhandling

If you get the error

> "could not find kernel image: ubuntu-installer/i386/linux"

first check if you adjusted the KERNEL and initrd to the correct path on your machine! If thats correct, those will give you some more hints:

```
ps aux | grep tftp
ss -apu | grep tftp
```

probably, you have to kill 
`in.tftpd` and `inetutils-inetd`
and restart all services while looking at the log:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog &
/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
killall in.tftpd
/etc/init.d/inetutils-inetd stop
service tftpd-hpa restart
ps aux | grep tftp
ss -apu | grep tftp
```

probably there you find the message

> cannot bind to local IPv4 socket: Address already in use
>   if that message is gone, it should all work fine

### Restart normal networking

When you are done, you can restart the NetworkManager by

```
service network-manager restart
```

If you use WiFi deactivate the eth0 card by

```
 ifconfig eth0 down
```

---

Now there is only one more open question:
[Bad Archive Mirror using PXE networkboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/491740/bad-archive-mirror-using-pxe-networkboot)

Comment: Q&A-style with own research! +1

Comment: rubo77, Are you sure that we don't need a Netboot iso for this? Desktop iso with `syslinux` is enough?