# How do I boot Ubuntu from the network?

Tags: installation, boot, networking

Is there an easy way to boot ubuntu from network a.k.a. PXE?

I would like to setup a PXE server, connect an old laptop (without cdrom nor working usb-boot-option) to the network and boot Ubuntu through the network.

I found [this howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet)

but that seems a bit much for just that little installation. Or the manpage is somewhat overwhelming. what is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an "easy" way, but this link might be slightly less over whelming.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer

Comment: thx, i triedI put it together here: http://askubuntu.com/a/272530/34298 But there is still one question open: how to configure my fritzbox

Comment: I fixed it all there: http://askubuntu.com/a/272530/34298